# Почему GitHub запрашивает login и пароль каждый раз когда я делаю push?

Tags: git, github

Это мой репозиторий и я сам туда хочу сделать пуш

Давно не использовал GitHub и вот сейчас создал там новый репозиторий, хочу загрузить проект, но он просит мой логин и пароль. Значит все пользователи этого репо должны знать логин и пароль от моего гитхаб, чтоб сделать коммит?

Всегда на гитхабе было так, есть ссылка на репозиторий, можешь сделать пуш.

Что сейчас поменялось?

Comment: Когда это можно было push-ить напрямую в чужие репозитории, в обход pull request-ов?

Comment: Какой программой вы пользовались раньше и какой сейчас? [Просто git-ом](https://git-scm.com/) или [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)? И где именно у(на каком этапе) у вас спрашивают имя пользователя и пароль?

Comment: @Arhad так не в чужие, а в свои. Я создавал новый репо и спокойно туда делал пуш. Никаких проблем

Comment: @Arhad Пользуюсь обычным терминалом. пишу git push origin master и вот получаю запрос на логин и пароль

Comment: Значит что-то произошло с SSH-ключом. Он исчез либо у вас на компьютере, либо у GitHub-а. Следует [сгенерировать новый ключ](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), затем [добавить его на Github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

Comment: Видимо у вас реозиторий добавлен через http поменяйте на ssh и добавите публичный ключ в гитхаб

Answer (score 7):

Потому что пуш в репозиторий требует аутентификации пользователя. Другим пользователям будет нужно вводить логин и пароль от своего аккаунта, после чего будет проверяться есть ли у них доступ на пуш в конкретный репозиторий.

Для избежания постоянного ввода логина и пароля есть два варианта:

1. Включить кеширование логина и пароля командой `git config credential.helper cache`

   ```
   $ git config credential.helper cache
   $ git push http://example.com/repo.git
   Username: <type your username>
   Password: <type your password>

   [work for 5 more minutes]
   $ git push http://example.com/repo.git
   [your credentials are used automatically]
   ```
2. Добавить SSH ключ в профиль [гитхаба](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)